# how does rails server serve pages even when app server puma is down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I noticed that when puma server was shutdown and when the site was visited the following rails error page was displayed.

[image]

I thought puma app server needed to be up in order to view this page. When the app server is down how is this page being served? Is nginx serving this page?

Comment: see the log file of the app

Comment: @praga2050 please read the question carefully.

Comment: Puma does have to be up indeed to serve this from public/500.html

Comment: @JoshBrody Thanks Josh. Can you look at this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576675/puma-server-silently-crashes-in-production-without-log

Comment: Are you using the reverse proxy server like `nginx` or `apache` ?

Comment: @Зелёный Yes i am using nginx as reverse proxy.

Comment: @Зелёный I see so nginx is serving the public files in rails project?

Comment: @Зелёный if that is the case then that explains why it is working even though puma is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought puma app server needed to be up in order to view this page.
>   When the app server is down how is this page being served? Is nginx
>   serving this page?

By default Rails doesnt serve static files from public folder, the page you see is a static file which is served by nginx.

There is an option in Rails:

```
# Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
# Apache or NGINX already handles this.
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

Comment: can you please look at this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576675/puma-server-silently-crashes-in-production-without-log